# Push array into array in Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to get the push() method on a loop to build a structure as follows:

```
var locations2 = [
    ['User', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 1],
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 2],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 3],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 4],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 5],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 6]
];
```

This is my code:

```
var locations = [];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/map.php",
    data: "name=test",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.points, function(i,item){
            array_push = ["test", parseFloat(item.origem_lat), parseFloat(item.origem_lng), i];
            locations.push(array_push);
        });               
    }
});
```

However, the Javascript console.log for locations shows an empty array.

I have tried to use push() in many different ways, but I cannot get the same structure as locations2. The biggest problem here is that I do not know how many arrays are going to be inside the locations array before the loop, so I can't initialize it beforehand.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your syntax looks right -- are you sure `data.points` contains the array you're expecting?

Comment: Add an error callback to your ajax call. It may be throws an error but you may not know with this code.

Comment: You can do a quick dump of your array contents with alert( JSON.stringify(x) ) where x is the array in question.

Comment: Do not forget to put the `console.log` statement in the callback, otherwise it won't be populated yet.

Comment: The Ajax call is fine, I can console.log each JSON element and it working as expected. The only problem is pushing the array in the same structure as locations2.

Comment: I tried below code it works fine. I think you can check the structure of data.points $.each([{origem_lat:"1.0", origem_lng:"1.1"}, {origem_lat:"2.0", origem_lng:"2.1"} ], function(i,item){
            array_push = ["test", parseFloat(item.origem_lat), parseFloat(item.origem_lng), i];
            locations.push(array_push);
        });

Comment: please post your result json to validate!

Comment: When and how do you use `console.log`?

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome. Please post the data you receive from the server.

Comment: Is the array always empty when you first populate it? Have you tried: `locations[i] = array_push` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. It has nothing to do with the push() method itself. Apparently ajax calls are not executed in sequential order (that's the reason it's asynchronous). I added **async: false** in the ajax call options and now everything works perfectly.

Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: `async: false` defeats the whole purpose of using **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**. You'll run into problems like page hangs etc because your requests are now blocking. Maybe look into **Deferred Objects** http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: +1 for mentioning deferreds. Its worth mentioning that there's a little bit of a learning curve, but they aren't too bad at all and are well suited for situations like these.